# Is it possible to add polygon type of feature class into network mesh?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, arccatalog, network-dataset

According to [this](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/what-is-a-network-dataset.htm) article Network dataset contains basic features. Like Point and Line.
I want to add Polygon feature classes into the dataset, how do I do it?

Is there an additional step to connect the polyline to the roads?

Comment: What role your polygon is going to play in network?

Comment: I have polygon features of residental building and I hope the routing can allow me to cut through these buildings to save time.

Comment: You can convert them to polylines. Don't forget to connect them to roads, otherwise they'll become closed circuit good for racing in loops only

Comment: how do you do that?  like connect them to roads? I thought if i add everything into the network it will work no? :o